# Tab is out of focus on clicking outside

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jsp

I have a webpage with four tabs. It is working fine except when I click outside the div,containing the tabs and its contents, the focus on the active tab is lost which is not desired.

**Code**

```
<body>
<img src="images/2.png" style="width: 950px; height: 60px;">
<div style="margin-top: -50px; margin-left: 5px; position: absolute; font-size: 32px; color: green;">Test
</div>
<div style="width: 69px; height: 57px; margin-left: 951px; margin-top: -58px;">
  <a href="#" title="Logout"><img src="images/logout.png" style="width: 78px; height: 73px;"></a>
</div>
<div style="margin-top: 100px;">
  <ul id="tabs" class="tab">
    <li><a id="load" href="#" class="tablinks" onclick="openTab(event, 'Reference')">Reference</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="tablinks" onclick="openTab(event, 'TestStrategy')">Test Strategy</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="tablinks" onclick="openTab(event, 'TestCase')">Test Case</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="tablinks" onclick="openTab(event, 'TestSummary')">Test Summary</a></li>
  </ul>

  <img src="images/line.png" style="margin-top: -14px; margin-left: 6px; width: 700px; height: 4px; position: absolute;">

  <div id="Reference" class="tabcontent">
    <p>Document_1.docx</p>
    <hr align="left">
    <p>Document_2.docx</p>
    <hr align="left">
    <p>Document_3.docx</p>
    <hr align="left">
  </div>

  <div id="TestStrategy" class="tabcontent">
    <p>TS_1.docx</p>
    <hr align="left">
    <p>TS_2.docx</p>
    <hr align="left">
  </div>

  <div id="TestCase" class="tabcontent">
    <p>TC_1.xlsx</p>
    <hr align="left">
    <p>TC_2.xlsx</p>
    <hr align="left">
    <p>TC_3.xlsx</p>
    <hr align="left">
    <p>TC_4.xlsx</p>
    <hr align="left">
    <p>TC_5.xlsx</p>
    <hr align="left">
  </div>

  <div id="TestSummary" class="tabcontent">
    <p>Summary_1.docx</p>
    <hr align="left">
    <p>Summary_2.pdf</p>
    <hr align="left">
    <p>Summary_3.ppt</p>
    <hr align="left">
  </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/heh9ptvy/).

How to resolve this?

Comment: That's the desired behaviour. You would need to add a `class` to the active tab to preserve the styles

Comment: Your tabs doesn't even work.

Comment: It is working in my eclipse. Not sure why it is not displaying properly in fiddle

Comment: Did you try to use `ul.tab li a.active` selector instead of only `.active`?

Comment: Yes I did that only `ul.tab li a:focus, .active`

Comment: @makshh is right. http://output.jsbin.com/kuripuh

Comment: `ul.tab li a:focus, .active {
    background-color: black;
}`            Missing your css

Comment: Yes it is working but for the first tab(onload) it is still the same.

Comment: first time onload give active class for first link(a).

Comment: Yes...it's working as expected now. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Have a look attached snippet

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 alert("Loaded");
 document.getElementById('Reference').style.display = "block";
 document.getElementById('load').focus();
  
  

});

function openTab(evt, tabName) {
 //alert(evt + "-" + tabName);
    // Declare all variables
    var i, tabcontent, tablinks;

    // Get all elements with class="tabcontent" and hide them
    tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
    for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
        tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
    }

    // Get all elements with class="tablinks" and remove the class "active"
    tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
    for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
        tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
    }

    // Show the current tab, and add an "active" class to the link that opened the tab
    document.getElementById(tabName).style.display = "block";
    evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
}
```

```css
body {
 font-family:"Segoe UI";
 font-size:75%;
 width:1024px;
/* height: 760px;*/
 line-height:1;
 outline:none;
 overflow:auto;
 background:url(../images/1.png);
 margin:0 auto;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-size: 1024px 760px;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: center; 
/*    background-color: #cccccc;*/
}

.active{
background:#333f50 !important;
}
hr {
    height: 10px;
    width: 69.2%;
/*    margin-left: -7px;*/
    border: 0;
    box-shadow: 0 10px 6px -10px #bababa inset;
}

/* Style the list */
ul.tab {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin-left: 5px;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
/*    border: 3px solid red;*/
    width: 485px;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

/* Float the list items side by side */
ul.tab li {float: left;}

/* Style the links inside the list items */
ul.tab li a {
    display: inline-block;
    color: white;
    background-color: #ADB9CA;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: 0.3s;
    font-size: 17px;
    font-family:Segoe UI;
    border: 1px solid #CCC;
/*    margin-left: 2px;*/
}

/* Change background color of links on hover */
ul.tab li a:hover {background-color: #ddd;}

/* Create an active/current tablink class */
ul.tab li a:focus, .active {background-color: #333F50;}

/* Style the tab content */
.tabcontent {
    display: none;
    padding: 6px 12px;
/*    border: 1px solid #ccc;*/
    border-top: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="images/2.png" style="width: 950px; height: 60px;">
<div
 style="margin-top: -50px; margin-left: 5px; position: absolute; font-size: 32px; color: green;">Test
</div>
<div style="width: 69px; height: 57px; margin-left: 951px; margin-top: -58px;">
<a href="#" title="Logout"><img src="images/logout.png" style="width: 78px; height: 73px;"></a>
</div>
<div style="margin-top: 100px;">
<ul id="tabs" class="tab">
 <li><a id="load" href="#" class="tablinks" onclick="openTab(event, 'Reference')">Reference</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="tablinks" onclick="openTab(event, 'TestStrategy')">Test Strategy</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="tablinks" onclick="openTab(event, 'TestCase')">Test Case</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="tablinks" onclick="openTab(event, 'TestSummary')">Test Summary</a></li>
  
</ul>
</div>
<img src="images/line.png"
 style="margin-top: -14px; margin-left: 6px; width: 700px; height: 4px; position: absolute;">

<div id="Reference" class="tabcontent">
<p>Document_1.docx</p>
<hr align="left">
<p>Document_2.docx</p>
<hr align="left">
<p>Document_3.docx</p>
<hr align="left">
</div>

<div id="TestStrategy" class="tabcontent">
<p>TS_1.docx</p>
<hr align="left">
<p>TS_2.docx</p>
<hr align="left">
</div>

<div id="TestCase" class="tabcontent">
<p>TC_1.xlsx</p>
<hr align="left">
<p>TC_2.xlsx</p>
<hr align="left">
<p>TC_3.xlsx</p>
<hr align="left">
<p>TC_4.xlsx</p>
<hr align="left">
<p>TC_5.xlsx</p>
<hr align="left">
</div>

<div id="TestSummary" class="tabcontent">
<p>Summary_1.docx</p>
<hr align="left">
<p>Summary_2.pdf</p>
<hr align="left">
<p>Summary_3.ppt</p>
<hr align="left">
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please mention the changes you made.

Comment: You have to add css for your active class . Add this code and let me know if not working ...    `.active{
background:#333f50 !important;
}`

Answer (score 1):

If you could use the tab name in `title`, here is a much tidier code. [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/c5q7Lus7/1/)

```js
$(function() {
  var tab = $('.active').attr('title');
  $('#' + tab).show();

  $('ul.tab a').click(function() {
    tab = $(this).attr('title');
    $('.tabcontent').hide();
    $('ul.tab a').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
    $('#' + tab).show();
  });
})
```

```css
body {
  font-family: "Segoe UI";
  font-size: 75%;
  width: 1024px;
  /* height: 760px;*/
  line-height: 1;
  outline: none;
  overflow: auto;
  background: url(../images/1.png);
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 1024px 760px;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: center;
  /*    background-color: #cccccc;*/
}

hr {
  height: 10px;
  width: 69.2%;
  /*    margin-left: -7px;*/
  border: 0;
  box-shadow: 0 10px 6px -10px #bababa inset;
}


/* Style the list */

ul.tab {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin-left: 5px;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  /*    border: 3px solid red;*/
  width: 485px;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}


/* Float the list items side by side */

ul.tab li {
  float: left;
}


/* Style the links inside the list items */

ul.tab li a {
  display: inline-block;
  color: white;
  background-color: #ADB9CA;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: 0.3s;
  font-size: 17px;
  font-family: Segoe UI;
  border: 1px solid #CCC;
  /*    margin-left: 2px;*/
}


/* Change background color of links on hover */

ul.tab li a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}


/* Create an active/current tablink class */

ul.tab li a:focus,
ul.tab li a.active {
  background-color: #333F50;
}


/* Style the tab content */

.tabcontent {
  display: none;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  /*    border: 1px solid #ccc;*/
  border-top: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="images/2.png" style="width: 950px; height: 60px;">
<div style="margin-top: -50px; margin-left: 5px; position: absolute; font-size: 32px; color: green;">Test
</div>
<div style="width: 69px; height: 57px; margin-left: 951px; margin-top: -58px;">
  <a href="#" title="Logout"><img src="images/logout.png" style="width: 78px; height: 73px;"></a>
</div>
<div style="margin-top: 100px;">
  <ul id="tabs" class="tab">
    <li><a class="active" href="#" class="tablinks" title="Reference">Reference</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="tablinks" title="TestStrategy">Test Strategy</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="tablinks" title="TestCase">Test Case</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="tablinks" title="TestSummary">Test Summary</a></li>
  </ul>

  <img src="images/line.png" style="margin-top: -14px; margin-left: 6px; width: 700px; height: 4px; position: absolute;">

  <div id="Reference" class="tabcontent">
    <p>Document_1.docx</p>
    <hr align="left">
    <p>Document_2.docx</p>
    <hr align="left">
    <p>Document_3.docx</p>
    <hr align="left">
  </div>

  <div id="TestStrategy" class="tabcontent">
    <p>TS_1.docx</p>
    <hr align="left">
    <p>TS_2.docx</p>
    <hr align="left">
  </div>

  <div id="TestCase" class="tabcontent">
    <p>TC_1.xlsx</p>
    <hr align="left">
    <p>TC_2.xlsx</p>
    <hr align="left">
    <p>TC_3.xlsx</p>
    <hr align="left">
    <p>TC_4.xlsx</p>
    <hr align="left">
    <p>TC_5.xlsx</p>
    <hr align="left">
  </div>

  <div id="TestSummary" class="tabcontent">
    <p>Summary_1.docx</p>
    <hr align="left">
    <p>Summary_2.pdf</p>
    <hr align="left">
    <p>Summary_3.ppt</p>
    <hr align="left">
  </div>
</div>
```